# How to increase line spacing in Plain TeX?

Tags: line-spacing, plain-tex

I want to increase the line spacing of my Plain TeX document (I use the XeTeX engine).

Is setting `\baselineskip=1.2\baselineskip` enough or should I also update `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit` or other parameters so that everything (including maths) looks good?

Comment: `\cases` and `\matrix` use `\normalbaselines`, which sets `\baselineskip` to `\normalbaselineskip`. Depending on your intention it might be necessary to change `\normalbaselineskip` as well—or exactly not. What looks good is not least a question of taste and therefore somehow opinion based.

Comment: \lineskip is used  to provide a gap when two things would othersize run into each other.  In other words, it is used when the line spacing fails.